# GC.Collect versus Marshal.ReleaseComObject and RCW

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, interop

I have a COM object reference in my C# that on occasion I require to be discarded by being set to Null then recreated. It seems that there is some caching going on or something that can result in the 'COM object has been seperated from it's underlying RCW' type of error. I got around this by forcing a GC.Collect immediately after setting the object to Null to discard the RCW but this heavy handed and inefficient approach is bad.

I wanted to use Marshal.ReleaseComObject but that just decrements the ref count and the issue remains until the GC actually runs. (Not to mention calling that is also a bad idea in general)

How can I ensure that upon recreation of the COM reference I get a new RCW and everything behaves as it should?

Comment: ew. you are mixing and matching the the COM unmanaged resources with the .NET GC. Bad idea.

Comment: Doesn't the RC Wrapper implement IDisposable?

Comment: The RCW is 'under the hood' I am just creating an object defined in a VB library, hooking up events and calling methods as usual. When I rapidly replace the objects with newly defined ones (they are part of an underlying data source for a grid) I can get this situation that can be solved by forcing GC.Collect.

Comment: You need to be really careful about when you release your COM objects and how you're using them. You say that you're hooking up events and stuff, are you unsubscribing them before disposing the object? If you're using any properties of the object elsewhere are you disposing them? And when referencing properties or getting child objects, are you assigning them to temporary variables and disposing of them?

Comment: If there was a genuine reference still in existence, would not GC.Collect fail to collect the object?